# 'int' object is not callable How to solve this error?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, integer

This seems very simple although is not running, obviously i miss something here. I want the user to enter for example 5 and to print 0 1 2 3 4.

```
value = input("Insert a number from 0 to 9\n: ")
value_int = int(value)

for i in value_int:
print(i)
```

Comment: You probably did `int = ....` somewhere before, thus replacing the builtin `int` function by an integer. You could `del int` and try again or, if this is part of a script, rename the `int` variable that you used before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - you need to use range() to generate an iterable sequence of numbers:

```
value = input("Insert a number from 0 to 9\n: ")
value_int = int(value)

for i in range(0,value_int):
    print(i)
```